# Loops & state management in test.check

Tags: clojure, test.check

With the introduction of Spec, I try to write test.check generators for all of my functions. This is fine for simple data structures, but tends to become difficult with data structures that have parts that depend on each other.   In other words, some state management within the generators is then required.

It would already help enormously to have generator-equivalents of Clojure's loop/recur or reduce, so that a value produced in one iteration can be stored in some aggregated value that is then accessible in a subsequent iteration.

> One simple example where this would be required, is to write a generator for splitting up a collection into exactly X partitions, with each partition having between zero and Y elements, and where the elements are then randomly assigned to any of the partitions. (Note that `test.chuck`'s `partition` function does not allow to specify X or Y).
>
> If you write this generator by looping through the collection, then this would require access to the partitions filled up during previous iterations, to avoid exceeding Y.

Does anybody have any ideas? Partial solutions I have found:

- test.check's `let` and `bind` allow you to generate a value and then reuse that value later on, but they do not allow iterations.
- You can iterate through a collection of previously generated values with a combination of the `tuple` and `bind`functions, but these iterations do not have access to the values generated during previous iterations.

  `(defn bind-each [k coll] (apply tcg/tuple (map (fn [x] (tcg/bind (tcg/return x) k)) coll))`
- You can use atoms (or volatiles) to store & access values generated during previous iterations. This works, but is very un-Clojure, in particular because you need to `reset!` the atom/volatile before the generator is returned, to avoid that their contents would get reused in the next call of the generator.
- Generators are monad-like due to their `bind` and `return` functions, which hints at the use of a monad library such as Cats in combination with a State monad. However, the State monad was removed in Cats 2.0 (because it was allegedly not a good fit for Clojure), while other support libraries I am aware of do not have formal Clojurescript support. Furthermore, when implementing a State monad in his own library, Jim Duey — one of Clojure's monad experts — seems to warn that the use of the State monad is not compatible with test.check's shrinking (see the bottom of http://www.clojure.net/2015/09/11/Extending-Generative-Testing/), which significantly reduces the merits of using test.check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the iteration you're describing by combining `gen/let` (or equivalently `gen/bind`) with explicit recursion:

```
(defn make-foo-generator
  [state]
  (if (good-enough? state)
    (gen/return state)
    (gen/let [state' (gen-next-step state)]
      (make-foo-generator state'))))
```

**However**, it's worth trying to avoid this pattern if possible, because each use of `let`/`bind` undermines the shrinking process. Sometimes it's possible to reorganize the generator using `gen/fmap`. For example, to partition a collection into a sequence of X subsets (which I realize is not exactly what your example was, but I think it could be tweaked to fit), you could do something like this:

```
(defn partition
  [coll subset-count]
  (gen/let [idxs (gen/vector (gen/choose 0 (dec subset-count))
                             (count coll))]
    (->> (map vector coll idxs)
         (group-by second)
         (sort-by key)
         (map (fn [[_ pairs]] (map first pairs))))))
```

Comment: Thanks! (I now wonder why the thought of recursion had not naturally occurred to me...) Could you expand perhaps on your "undermines the shrinking process"? In my (admittedly still limited) testing with generators that contain many lets/binds, I seemed to be happy with the shrinking that happened. Do you know of any specific circumstances that are more likely to undermine the shrinking?

Comment: The issue is described here: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/TCHECK-112

Comment: I should also clarify that `gen/let` only results in a real `gen/bind` if you have multiple clauses or if the body is itself a generator. Otherwise it's equivalent to `gen/fmap`.